# jQuery to hide divs based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, dropdown

I've gone through a lot of the posts here already on how to do this, and I've tried multiple times to implement them on my website. I'm not a developer by any means, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I've tried different jQuery scripts and have had some success, but I can't really wrap my head around it as I've never done any real scripting myself.

I'm currently using wordpress to set up a shop, and I need the ability to have users select an option from a dropdown menu. Depending on the option they select, it shows or hides a div with a certain class.
Using wordpress, I also don't have the ability to modify the core files, so I'm looking for a solution that'll work with the existing code.

My dropdown looks like this, and I'm not able to change how this is structured:

```
<div class="fes-fields">
    <select data-required="1" data-type="select" name="download_tag[]" id="download_tag" class="download_tag">
        <option value="-1">— Select —</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="29">Resources</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="28">Training</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The initial value which **Select**, then there's the option to select either **Resources** or **Training**
When Select is active, none of the divs should be visible. But Selecting either Resources or Training should display their respective divs.

Here's an example of one of the divs:

```
<div class="fes-el section_break section_break_1511992265 resource-duplicate">      
    <div class="fes-section-wrap">
        <h2 class="fes-section-title">Resources</h2>
        <div class="fes-section-details">If you're uploading resources, this is where you specify which categories applies</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've appended the class **'resource-duplicate'** and **'training-duplicate'** to the appropriate divs. This should help show and hide the correct divs depending on the option selected.

An example of another div, this one is just a list of selectable options:

```
<div class="fes-el taxonomy level training-duplicate">  
    <div class="fes-label">
        <label for="level">Level </label>
    </div>
    <div class="fes-fields">
        <ul class="fes-category-checklist">
            <li id="level-30">
                <label class="selectit">
                    <input value="30" type="checkbox" name="level[]" id="in-level-30">  
                     Beginner
                </label>
            </li>
            <li id="level-32">
                <label class="selectit">
                    <input value="32" type="checkbox" name="level[]" id="in-level-32"> 
                    Expert
                </label>
            </li>  
            <li id="level-31">
                <label class="selectit">
                    <input value="31" type="checkbox" name="level[]" id="in-level-31">  
                    Intermediate
                </label>
            </li>  
        </ul>  
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried implementing this script:
http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/wSW7z/
I got as far as hiding my content, but couldn't get it to work based on any of my selections.

I know it might be a bit much to ask, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Morten

Comment: You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wSW7z/279/

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.
The .fes-el element that is being used however is now hiding all content on the website. This is because all of my elements start with this. So if there's a way to modify the script to just look at the training-duplicate and resource-duplicate?

Comment: Just a minor fix http://jsfiddle.net/wSW7z/280/

Comment: Thank you! You've saved me so much time and pain!

Comment: Glad to help @MjTheHunter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a minor refactor in order to make that code works, but using the html classes from your code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.resource-duplicate , .training-duplicate').hide();
      $('#download_tag').change(function () {
         $('.resource-duplicate , .training-duplicate').hide();
         var choice = $('#download_tag option:selected').text()
         if(choice === 'Resources'){
            $('.resource-duplicate').show();
         }
         if(choice === 'Training'){
            $('.training-duplicate').show();
         }
      })
  });
```

You can see it working here: <kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wSW7z/280/)</kbd>

Comment: Just a quick followup, something I'm assuming is an issue with the way this theme is handling jQuery?

When I use the code snippet, it successfully hides and shows everything correctly. But all other elements on the page, such as clicking a button to prompt an upload don't work anymore. Is this something common with jQuery and where it's placed on the page? Or might it just be something strange with Wordpress ?

Thanks

Comment: It shouldn´t be an issue with the code itself...you can open another question and post the link here in the comment, try to include as much details as possible in the question.

Comment: I added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390219/jquery-renders-other-elements-on-page-non-responsive

Any help would really be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#selectMe').on('change', function() {
  $('.group').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
})
```

What's happening here is that you're checking for when the dropdown is changed, when it's changed, you hide all of your `.group` elements and you show the element that matches the currently selected value.

You could split this out a bit more so that you can see what's going on better like this:

```
$('#selectMe').on('change', function() {
  $('.group').hide();
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  $('#' + selectedValue).show();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Micheal, thanks for the reply, hackerman's solution above did the trick. But thanks for taking the time to help :)

Comment: @MjTheHunter no worries, I think all of the answers did virtually the same thing, hackerman's answer was just more well rounded and served the code up on a plate for you, they deserves to have their answer marked as the solution :) Best of luck

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.resource-duplicate{
    display: none;
}

.training-duplicate {
    display: none;
}
```

Then add this to your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#download_tag').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 29){      
            $('.training-duplicate').hide();
            $('.resource-duplicate').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.resource-duplicate').hide();
            $('.training-duplicate').show();        
        }
    });
});
```