# jQuery renders other elements on page non-responsive

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I got some help in a previous post regarding some jQuery code to have divs on a page display or be hidden depending on what was selected in a dropdown menu. That code works really well and does exactly what it's supposed to.

The previous post: [jQuery to hide divs based on dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386547/jquery-to-hide-divs-based-on-dropdown)

However, after implementing it on the page, all other elements no longer respond when clicked. It's a submissions page where users can upload their own products. I.e. they'll upload a thumbnail, some gallery images and their product.

But after implementing the jQuery snippet, it seems all other functionality is gone. Whenever any other buttons on the page are pressed, nothing is prompted any more.

I'm not a developer, so It's a little hard to troubleshoot. If anyone has suggestions to why this could be, I would be really grateful. I might be something simple that I've forgotten to do, something you always have to do with jQuery?

The page in question can be found here:
https://fn2.flippednormals.com/vendor-dashboard/?task=new-product

And you can login with these details

**user:
henry@mortenjaeger.com**

**pass:
henry@1234**

I'm hoping it's a user error on my side seeing as I know absolutely nothing about jQuery and how to really implement it. Especially on a wordpress site

And here's the jQuery code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.resource-duplicate , .training-duplicate').hide();
      $('#download_tag').change(function () {
         $('.resource-duplicate , .training-duplicate').hide();
         var choice = $('#download_tag option:selected').text()
         if(choice === 'Resources'){
            $('.resource-duplicate').show();
         }
         if(choice === 'Training'){
            $('.training-duplicate').show();
         }
      })
  });
</script>
```

Thanks!
Morten

Comment: You're including a really old version of jQuery. If you have other jQuery on your page and it worked before, try removing your include

Comment: Yeah, there's quite a few errors. Largely, they have to do with methods being called that were added in a later version -- mostly $(...).on(...) (you're using 1.6.4, and that was added in 1.7). Definitely, an update to which jQuery you point to would be wise.

Comment: Ah I see! Is there a specific version I need to go for, or will the latest one work with this code?

Comment: I added this version now https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
And everything seems to work perfectly, thank you so much!